# How to read in from a text file in C++?

Tags: c++, file, input

I am trying to read in from a text file. I believe that the syntax for opening a file would be:

```
ifstream file("Info.txt");
file.open("Info.txt");
```

If the file is formatted to read:

Dave
Gabe 8
Ryan 10 Green

Can I create 3 variables like so?

```
    string name;
    int age;
    string color;
```

Then read the information from the files like so?

```
    file >> name >> age >> color;
```

How is this file read in affected by some lines in the files not having the age and/or color?

Comment: You don't need to `open` the file if you pass the filename in the constructor. If your text file doesn't have properly formatted data on every single line, you'll either have to resort to using separators (like a CSV) or you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: I would suggest you to read all the file and save it in a std::string and then find what you want in that string

Comment: maybe you could call a system call that executes a bash command. Use 'cut' command to put each variable on a separate line in a new tmp file. from C++ read the tmp file and use getline() to put each line in a new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm admittedly not very familiar with the c++ string functions, but here's my attempt:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
     std::ifstream fin("Info.txt");
     if(!fin)
     {
             std::cout << "Error opening the file" << std::endl;
             return(1);
     }
    char* line_cstr = new char[1000];
    char name[1000];
    int age;
    char color[1000];
    char* rest = new char[1000];

    fin.getline(line_cstr, 1000);
    while ( strlen(line_cstr) != 0 ) {
        int numTokensRead = sscanf(line_cstr, "%s %d %s %1000[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", name, &age, color, rest);

        if ( numTokensRead >= 3  ) {
        std::cout <<"name: " << name <<", age: " << age <<", color: " << color <<"\n";
            strcpy(line_cstr, rest);
        }

        // do some error checking for incomplete entries
        else if (numTokensRead == 1) {
            if ( strlen(name) == strlen(line_cstr) ) {
                // we're done!
                return 0;
            }

            // skip the first token
            sscanf(line_cstr, "%*s %1000[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", line_cstr);
        }
        else if  (numTokensRead == 2) {
            // skip the first 2 tokens
            sscanf(line_cstr, "%*s %*d %1000[0-9a-zA-Z ]s", line_cstr);
        }
    }
}
```

Acting on the following text file:

## Info.txt

```
Mike 25 Red Dave Gabe 8 Green 10 Green
```

## output

```
$ ./a.out 
name: Mike, age: 25, color: Red
name: Gabe, age: 8, color: Green
```

I'm not 100% sure that this handles all possible error cases  - two ints in a row, a float, multiple lines, etc - but it should get you started.